# How do I mock call method from testable class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Want to ask you a question.

How should I properly return some data from method called from testable class ?

For example I have next structure:

```
Class SomeClass {
    public void method1(){
    //some logic here
    List<Object> howToReturnHereValues = gatData();
    //some logic here
    }
    public List<Object> getData(){

       return List<Object>;

    }
}
```

Right now I want to test `method1()`, but I don't know how to mock call `getData()` which returns `List<Object>`.

Any advice please ?

Comment: Take a look at `Spy` from Mockito. This allow you to Mock some methods of a "real" object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a spy, like explained here: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.17/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13

Example:

```
@Test
public void testMethod1() throws Exception {
    SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();
    SomeClass spy = Mockito.spy(someClass);
    Mockito.when(spy.getData()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList("blaat", "blabla"));
    spy.method1();
}
```

This will return a List of "blaat" and "blabla" which can be used by the logic in your method1.

Answer (score 2):

> Right now I want to test method1(), but I don't know how to mock call
>   getData() which returns List.

It is rather a bad idea to mock a public method of a class that is under test.

A unit test should test a behavior and mock dependencies. Here, you unit test only a part of the behavior as you mock the behavior of the tested class.

If the class is ours you could :

- either test this method without mocking the `getData()` called public method.
- or move the `getData()` public method in another class and then mock this new dependency if you don't want to repeat the test of the `getData()` method in each test method calling it.

If the class is not modifiable and the mocked called is really required, you could use the `spy()` method of the Mockito framework on the object under test to simulate a mocked behavior for a specific method.